# Quantum mechanics perturbation and the orthogonality of energy states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hilbert-space, perturbation-theory, dirac-delta-distributions

Consider the following question and its solution:

[image]

[image]

My question is concerning the solution of $a_{nm}$.
Surely if the energy eigenstates are orthogonal then $a_{nm}$ must be equal to zero. WHy is this not the case?

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Orthogonality of the energy eigenstates $|u_n \rangle$ means that for $m \neq n$

$$\langle u_m | u_n \rangle = \int u^*_m u_n dx = 0 $$

It doesn't require that

$$\langle u_m | F | u_n \rangle = \int u^*_m F(x) u_n dx = 0 $$
for any operator **F**.

So, in general, the quantity 
$$a_{nm} = \frac{\langle u_m | \delta V(x) | u_n \rangle}{E_n - E_m} $$

is not necessarily zero.